# Radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n+1}$ are both equal to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

**The question:**

If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=L$, prove that the power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n+1}$ have both radius of convergence equal to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$.

**My work:**

I just try to solve the limit with the series, for the first one, I think things gone right:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_nx^{2n}|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\sqrt[n]{|(x^2)^n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}|x^2|\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=|x|^2\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|},$$

using the hipotesis, we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_nx^{2n}|}=|x|^2\cdot L.$$

We need the convergence, so this limit needs to be $<1$:

$$|x|^2\cdot L<1\Rightarrow |x|<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}.$$

So, the radius of convergence is, in fact, $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$.

Now, for the second series, I had a problem when I developed the same way because I can't isolate $|x|$ with only $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$ in the other side, so I reach to this:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_nx^{2n+1}|}=\dots=L\cdot|x|^2\cdot\sqrt[n]{|x|}<1\Rightarrow\dots\Rightarrow|x|\cdot\sqrt[2n]{|x|}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}.$$

I tried to see the both series with even and odd powers, like separated cases, but didn't work too...

Comment: $\lim \sqrt[n]{|x|}=1$ for $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is perfect. On your second resolution, you can't drop the limit yet, as your expression still depends on $n$. That way, you will be left with the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|x|}$ and therefore the desired conclusion is achieved.